# Child cannot re-render correctly after change in parent even with unique key is provided

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I built a small recursive component for generating a config json.
Everything works find until I am trying to add value and delete one of them (among of three).

Lets say there are three "Title" component with value of 1,2,3 accordingly, once I delete the middle "Title" component, its parent json maintain correctly, however, the children not rendering correctly according to parent json.

I know that a unique key should be provided to each array child and I did provide a unique key for each of them, but still not re-rendering correctly.

**Before delete the second "Title" component:**

[image: Before delete the second "Title" Component]

**After delete the second "Title" component, you can see the parent json is correct, however, not the rendered part.**

[[image: After delete the second "Title" Component[2]]

Here are the snippet of my code:

```
class Row extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        ...this.props.state
    }
    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.renderType = this.renderType.bind(this);
}
renderType = (type) => {
    switch(type){
        case ("Title"):
            return ([{
                                "type": "TITLE",
                                "config": {},
                                "titleText": ""
                            }])
        case ("Input"):
            return ([{
                                "type": "INPUT",
                                "config": {},
                                "InputType": ""
                            }])
        default:
            return null
    }
}
handleAdd = (index,type) =>{
    const oldState = this.state;
    let newContainerObj = this.renderType(type);
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        content: oldState.content.concat(newContainerObj)
    },
    //After changed child's state, change parent state
        ()=>{
            this.props.onChange(this.props.index,this.state);
        }
    )
}
handleDelete = (i) =>{
    const oldState = this.state;
    const newContent = [...oldState.content]
    if(i>=0){
        newContent.splice(i,1);
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            content: newContent
        },
            //after deleted element, update parent
            ()=>{
                this.props.onChange(this.props.index,this.state);
            }
        )
    }
}
handleSubElementChange=(index, subContent)=>{
    const newContent = this.state.content.map((item, j) => {
        if (j === index) {
            return subContent;
        } else {
            return item;
        }
    });
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        content:newContent
    },
        ()=>{
            this.props.onChange(this.props.index, this.state);
        }
    )
}
render() {
    let pState = this.state;
    let content = pState.content;
    const index = this.props.index;
    let renderComponent = null;

    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <p>Row: {this.props.index+1}</p>
            {true&&<pre>{JSON.stringify(content,undefined,2)}</pre>}
            {
                content.map((child,i)=>
                        <div className={`wrapper ${this.props.level}-${i} `} key={`${this.props.level}-${i}`}>
                            <button className="btn btn-danger delete" onClick={()=>{this.handleDelete(i)}}>X</button>
                            {false&&<pre>{JSON.stringify(child,undefined,2)}</pre>}
                            <Recursor state={child} index={i} onChange={this.handleSubElementChange} level={this.props.level+1} />

                        </div>
                )
            }
            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={()=>{this.handleAdd(index,"Title")}}> + Title </button>
            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={()=>{this.handleAdd(index,"Input")}}> + Input </button>
        </div>
    )}}
```

This is the JsFiddle Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/3wnrq60p/

Comment: Your `key` is based on the `index` this is an [anti pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Comment: My key is based on the combination of level + ‘-‘ + index, which is not simply index and should be unique, is it still not valid for this case?

Comment: If you are deleting or reordering the array the problem still persists, cause when the `index` changes the key will change as well

Comment: Thanks @Dupocas , I will try to use the shortid() instead, or do you have any suggestion. Which unique id should I use? since the output Json will be stored into a database, which I don’t want too many meaningless data( like unique id generated by shortid()) to be stored into a database.